# Installing Windows SDK / Kits 8.1 / 10

Tags: windows, sdk, signtool

Since Microsoft now requires sha256 for signed downloads, I need to update signtool.exe which is part of the Windows SDK / kit.

The Windows Kis SDKs should be good (I am using Windows 10) but I am getting an error when trying to install (both online with the setup and the redistributable download)

Here's the log:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 26-01-2016  01:36:42  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: X:\AppData\Local\Temp\{ed3a6e6d-9661-4357-abe4-fcc03dc57a07}\.be\sdksetup.exe ===
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:340]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:340]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:340]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{984022F2-9BCA-A41D-6A38-1AE658F01415}v8.100.25984\Installers\Windows Software Development Kit-x86_en-us.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:340]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:340]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:634]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:634]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:638]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (F8:04) [01:36:42:651]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{984022F2-9BCA-A41D-6A38-1AE658F01415}v8.100.25984\Installers\Windows Software Development Kit-x86_en-us.msi
MSI (s) (F8:04) [01:36:42:651]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (F8:68) [01:36:42:654]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (F8:04) [01:36:42:655]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (F8:04) [01:36:42:655]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (F8:04) [01:36:42:655]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (F8:04) [01:36:42:656]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (F8:04) [01:36:42:657]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (F8:04) [01:36:42:658]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:659]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (70:E4) [01:36:42:660]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 26-01-2016  01:36:42 ===
```

I have tried installing itto default path and altenative path. I have also tried selecting only to install one thing. Same result no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it.

- Install SDK on another computer.
- Zip
- Move to computer where SDK install is not working.
- Start using the new signtool