# Altenative place/way to download signtool / replacement

Tags: signtool

For whatever reason, I seem unable to install this SDK
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

But I need a new signtool.exe for signing my downloads with sha256 certificate.

Is there any semi-official place I can download the raw tools or a replacement?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way by installing he offidical SDK on another Win10 machine and then copy/paste installation.

[Installing Windows SDK / Kits 8.1 / 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005230/installing-windows-sdk-kits-8-1-10/35017766#35017766)